# How to retrieve directory used in try_files directive?

Tags: nginx

I have a hard time figuring out how try_files directive work.
This configuration works as expected if index file is used (http://domain.com/):

```
X-Fcgi-Script-Name  /main_apps/domain.com/index.php
X-Script-Filename   /var/www/main_apps/domain.com/index.php
```

However if I specify PHP script (index.php or other) try_files find file as expected, but take a look at variables:

```
X-Fcgi-Script-Name  /index.php
X-Script-Filename   /var/www/index.php
```

So my question is: How can I find which directory was picked by try_files directive?

**Used server configuration**:

```
server {
    server_name  ~^(?P<domain>.+)$;
    root         /var/www;
    autoindex    off;
    index        index.php;


    try_files   /main_apps/$domain$uri/ /partners/$domain$uri/ =404;

    more_set_headers   "X-Script-Filename: $request_filename";
    more_set_headers   "X-Fcgi-Script-Name: $fastcgi_script_name";

    # Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
        include        php_fpm_params;
    }
}
```

**Note**: Nginx I use is compiled with 3rd party module [HeadersMore](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However if I specify PHP script (index.php or other) try_files find file as expected

You're wrong here. In this case your request handled by `location ~ \.php$` where no try_files.

btw, `server_name  ~^(?P<domain>.+)$;` is overkill. You should use [`$host` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You are wrong here, try_files find file successfully, otherwise it would result in 404 error...

Comment: But you have no `try_files` in `location ~ \.php$`.